# CodeIgniter - Grocery CRUD: Deleting a require upload file

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I have an issue when delete the upload file on edit. If upload field is require, after delete this file I can’t save the record. But if I close browser and open again, this record has empty upload field without any error.
Is there any solution?
Thanks.
EDIT:
Source code is very simple... just 2 lines

```
$crud->required_fields ( 'name', 'image', 'price' );
$crud->set_field_upload ( 'image', $this->config->item ( 'image_path' ) );
```

Comment: Please share code...?

Comment: It's only 2 lines, if you know Codeigniter - Grocery Crud. See my update. Thank you.